# import txt file to 2d array with scanner

Tags: java

I want to import a textfile to a 2d array with a scanner but can't really get it to work. The name for the textfile should import as an argument to the program.

This is what I got now right now, it prints out the right textfile but I can't get it to store it to the 2d array. And I have no clue how to get the name as an argument. How do I do that?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maze {
char[][] mazeArray;
private Position startPos;
private boolean[][] visited;

public void main(String[] args) {
    int totalRow = getNumRows();
    int totalColumn = getNumColumns();
    try {
        char[][] mazeArray = new char[totalRow][totalColumn];
        File f = new File("text.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(f);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(data);

        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (
            FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mazeArray));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few problems. The `main` method needs to be declared `static`.  Same for the member variable `mazeArray` if you want to access it from a `static` method. This is probably not what you want to do in the long run; you should create an instance of `Maze` and work with that, making `main` really small.

Then your code is incomplete, `Position`, `getNumColumns`, and `getNumRows` are missing. There is too much that you want your code to do (get the file name from the command line, fill the maze); it almost looks like you want us to write the code for you. That is why you're getting downvoted: you don't give us the necessary information to help you, and your code doesn't even compile, still you ask about its behavior as if it did compile. Pro tip: a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is really appreciated here.

Once your code compiles, you re-declare `mazeArray` in the `try` block. This creates a new separate variable that only lives to the end of that block. When you `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mazeArray));` that refers to the `mazeArray` class member, but that was never initialized. But then again, you never use the `mazeArray` in the `try` block either, so you effectively just read the lines in the file, print them, and ignore them.

You could write your code like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maze {
    // make the maze dimension constant (final) and move them outside the
    // function, they are probably needed elsewhere as well.
    static final int totalRow = 3;
    static final int totalColumn = 3;

    // declare that main can throw IOException, whuch us a base class for
    // FileNotFoundException, so that you don't have to handle it
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char[][] mazeArray = new char[totalRow][totalColumn];
        // take input file name from command line
        File f = new File(args[0]);
        // Change the try block to be a try-with-resources, so that the Scanner
        // gets automatically closed, even when there was an exception.
        // Remove the catch block as it didn't do anything useful anyway.
        try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(f)) {
            for (int r = 0; r < totalRow; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < totalColumn; c++) {
                    // read next token as String, and keep only the first character
                    String next = myReader.next();
                    mazeArray[c][r] = next.charAt(0);
                }
            }
        }
        // print the maze
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mazeArray));
    }
}
```

This works for an input file like this:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

and prints:

> [[a, d, g], [b, e, h], [c, f, i]]